# Refraction of light - Huygens' Principle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, waves, refraction, huygens-principle

To elucidate the rationale behind the bending of light as it transitions between different mediums, Huygens' principle is predominantly employed. The procedure, as demonstrated in this video (link: https://youtu.be/-wkGxFV3OAw?feature=shared), mirrors the common approach. However, it's not imperative for light rays to originate from a nearly infinite source relative to the interface, resulting in incident rays being parallel (an aesthetically convenient scenario). What if the light source is in close proximity, and no ray has a parallel counterpart? Can the bending of light still be explained in such instances?

Comment: See this recent post - [Explanation of diffraction of a single light ray by Huygens' principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/788237/37364). It is a different question, but my answer talks about Huygens' principle.